# Can I use submersible pump cable for an indoor/outdoor spa circuit?

Tags: wiring

I'm putting a spa on a second floor covered deck.  The main panel is in the basement 45 feet from first floor exterior.  Wiring would need to go through basement and then crawlspace.

I know I need conduit outside up to second floor disconnect. It is too complicated to run conduit all the way from main panel but can't run cable inside conduit outside.  I thought about transitioning from cable to THWN, but it would be almost impossible to put a box inside the crawlspace.

I saw 6/3 w/grnd submersible pump cable online.  It has sheathed ground (required by code). Can I run this stuff unprotected (but fastened, of course) indoors and then in conduit outside up to the GFCI disconnect? It would solve a lot of issues. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you considered using ENT (smurf tube) for the indoor portion of the run?

Comment: I added subjects to your sentences to make them more readable. This isn't telegraph and you aren't paying by the letter. :) Please take the [tour] to learn how to use this site.

Comment: This isn't part of your question, but make sure your deck is designed/approved for the weight of a spa.  They can be very heavy (especially if they hold a lot of water), and most decks aren't designed with that weight load in mind.  Especially on the 2nd floor where a catastrophic failure of the deck could be fatal.